# Django custom tags not rendered (GAE)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create Django custom tags with Google App Engine but for some reason it does not work all the time. I believe my tags are correctly registered as Django is parsing them but the render method is never called. The strangest thing is that my tags work when placed inside  a for loop {% for ... %} but never outside.

Here's the code:

in django/mytags.py

```
from django import template
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

register = webapp.template.create_template_register()

# This works all the time
@register.simple_tag
def hello_world():
    return u'Hello world'

@register.tag('foo')
def foo(parser, token):
    return FooNode()

class FooNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'

    def render(self, context):
        return self.foo
```

in main.py

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

template.register_template_library('django.mytags')

...

self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html', template_values))
```

in main.html

```
{% foo %}

{% for item in items %}
    {% foo %}
```

and the result:

```
<django.mytags.FooNode object at 0x000000001794BAC8>

foo
foo
foo
...
```

This is driving me insane. I suspect putting my tag in a for loop forces the node to be rendered (where it should have been done already).

Comment: Just a thought, but what if you add a `__unicode__()` function to the `FooNode` class?

Comment: @frb - Adding __unicode__() would just hide the problem in this case. I need the render() method to be called with the context as parameter to be able to do more than just returning a string.

Comment: @nhuon: But I thought render() always needs to return a string (even if it's empty)? P.S. I don't know why this is happening. It seems __init__() is not been called.

Comment: @stellarchariot - What I meant was that I need to use the context that is passed to the render() call to be able to select the right string to return. If the outcome of render was always the same I guess I would not bother myself with tags. As for __init__(), it's being called so the node is created but not rendered.

Comment: dig into your server and look at the code that has been auto-generated to implement the jsp page.  it will be there somewhere.  reading the code will probably explain what is happening.

Comment: Auto generated code, jsp? What?

Comment: Quick question, you have a file named django/mytags.py , does this mean you have your own module called django? Doesn't this conflict with appengine's supplied django module itself?

Comment: @NunoMaltez - for the purpose of posting I changed the name, the folder is not actually named django.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add string representation for you class

```
class FooNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'

    def render(self, context):
        return self.foo

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'string to put in template'
```

Comment: Works fine now with the string representation

Comment: Actually, I still have the same issue. It works in for loops, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to add `{% load mytags %}`? (Should be used, per [custom tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/))